# Method display on the scope is not executed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-show

I have a set of directives that share a scope

## Update:

The code is available as a plunk here http://plnkr.co/edit/JZ77bsZgGrw6N4K718Is?p=preview

## todo-item:

```
 app.directive("todoItem",function(DeleteTodo,$log){
var dirDefObj = {
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl:'app/templates/todo.html',
    scope:{
        todo:'=value'
    },
    controller:function($scope){},
    replace:true
};
return dirDefObj;
});
```

template:

```
<div class="ui card">
  <todo-formui ng-show="todo.editMode"></todo-formui>
  <todo-cardui ng-show="!todo.editMode"></todo-cardui>
</div>
```

There are two directives that inherit the scope of this directive:

## todo-cardui

```
app.directive('todoCardui',function(){
var dirDefObj = {
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl:'app/templates/display-todo.html',
    scope:false,
    replace:true,
    controller:function($scope)
    {
        $scope.clickDone = function clickDone(){
            //two tasks (1)toggle the done value on the todo (2) toggle the btnText on the todo
            $scope.todo.done = !$scope.todo.done;
            $scope.todo.btnText = $scope.todo.done?'Reinstate':'Done';
        };

        $scope.remove = function remove()
        {
            DeleteTodo.delete($scope.todo);
            $scope.$emit('todo:deleted',$scope.todo);
        };

        $scope.edit = function edit(value)
        {
            $scope.todo.editMode = true;
            $scope.savedState = angular.extend({},$scope.todo);
        };  
    }
};
return dirDefObj;
});
```

template:

```
 <div>
<div class="content">
    <i class="right floated blue pencil icon" ng-click="edit()"></i> 
    <header class="ui medium header">
        <span ng-class="{'done-todo':todo.done,'normal-todo':!todo.done}">{{todo.task}}</span>
    </header>
    <div class="description">
        <p>{{todo.description}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="extra content">
    <button class="ui small green toggle button floated left" ng-click="clickDone()">{{todo.btnText}}</button>
    <button class="ui small red button floated left" ng-click="remove()">Delete</button>
</div>
</div>
```

## todo-formui:

```
app.directive("todoFormui",function(EditService){
var dirDefObj = {
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl:'app/templates/edit-todo.html',
    scope:false,
    controller:function($scope){
        $scope.display = function display(){
            console.log("Inside the edit to preview function");
            $scope.editMode = false;
        };

        $scope.save = function(){
            EditService.edit($scope.todo);
        };

        $scope.discard = function(){
            $scope.todo={
                task:'',
                dscription:'',
                btnText:''
            };
            $scope.todo = $scope.savedState;

        };
    },
    replace:true
};
return dirDefObj;
});
```

template:

```
<div ng-class="{description:show_modal,content:!show_modal}">
<i class="right floated blue unhide icon" ng-click="display()"></i>
<form class="ui small form">
    <div class="field">
        <label>Task</label>
        <input type="text" name="task" placeholder="What do you want to do?"ng-model="todo.task">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea ng-model="todo.description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="two fields">
        <button class="ui red button floated right">Discard</button>
        <button class="ui submit green button floated right" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
    </div>  
</form>
```

When executing the code,I found that the display function in todo-formui would not execute,no matter where I put it or what I tried to do.The save function in the same scope runs with no problems.

Comment: Can you please try to reproduce this using something like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co), [jsBin](http://jsbin.com), [CodePen](http://codepen.io) or the inbuilt snippet support on StackOverflow?

Comment: You are aware that by declaring `scope: false` you are inheriting the same scope in your directive, thus extending it with new functions such as `display` etc. I don't think that is what you want to do.

Comment: @floribon I would like to use the two directives here https://github.com/vamsiampolu/angular-jspm-todo/blob/todo-state-transistion/app/templates/create-todo.html and I also want to have an animating transistion between them in the code in the question,can it be done using isolate scopes only...

Comment: @GregL I have updated the question with a plunker (near the top of the description) http://plnkr.co/edit/JZ77bsZgGrw6N4K718Is?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your preview function(as mentioned in plunker), you have to update the scope as

**$scope.todo.editMode = false;**

instead of

***$scope.editMode = false;***

then the preview will be avaliable

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

It's because the icon is under another html element and the click event isn't triggered. Add a clear after the "preview" icon (which is floated) to push the form where it should be. Use some DOM inspector and you will soon realize the problem.

Comment: I have tried setting the setting the z-index value so that the icon appears on top,it does not seem to have any effect on ordering. The updated plunk is here http://plnkr.co/edit/JZ77bsZgGrw6N4K718Is?p=preview

Comment: Have you ever considered to use a simple onclick event with an alert() inside? And see if that triggers?